# app engine chaining deferred transactional tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, deferred, transactional

When I call a deferred transactional task from a transactional function, `f`, `f` can commit while the deferred task fails.

HOWEVER, if I call `f` via a deferred call, the calling function fails.

To repro, I did the following:

```
@ndb.transactional()
def f():
  # modify datastore entity X
  ... 
  x.put()

class X(ndb.Model):
  ...
  def _post_put_hook(self, future)
    deferred.defer(y,
                   _transactional=ndb.in_transaction())
def y():
  raise Exception()
```

When I call `f`, the deferred task fails, but `x.put()` commits.

HOWEVER, if I call deferred.f, `x.put()` fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood what the `_transactional` optional argument in `deferred.defer(y, _transactional=ndb.in_transaction())` does. It doesn't mean that the deferred `y` execution will happen in *the same* transaction in which `deferred.defer()` was called, it only means that *enqueuing the deferred task* will happen if the transaction succeeds.

From [google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred):

> **google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.defer(obj, *args, **kwargs)**
>
> [...]
>
> - obj – The callable to execute. See module docstring for restrictions. _countdown, _eta, _headers, _name, _target,
>     **_transactional**, _url, _retry_options, _queue: Passed through to the task queue - see the task queue documentation for details.

And from [google.appengine.api.taskqueue.taskqueue module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.taskqueue.taskqueue#google.appengine.api.taskqueue.taskqueue.Queue.add):

> **add(task, transactional=False)**
>
> [...]
>
> - transactional – If `True`, transactional tasks will be added to the queue but cannot be run or leased until after the transaction
>     succeeds. If the transaction fails then the tasks will be removed from
>     the queue (and therefore will never run). If `False`, the added tasks
>     are available to run immediately; any enclosing transaction’s success
>     or failure is ignored.

The actual execution of the deferred task is done on another request, *always* in a different transaction context than the one where `deferred.defer()` was called. Which is why your deferred task may fail even if your original transaction is successful.